# Difference between fill and fill map

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I came across some code which was filling an array of objects like so:

```js
const getObj = () => {
  return {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
}

const arr = Array(3).fill(null).map(getObj);
console.log(arr);
```

However, I'm wondering what the main purpose of `fill(null).map(getObj)` is? It seems redundant as I can simply write the following and get the same resulting array:

```js
const getObj = () => {
  return {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
}

const arr = Array(3).fill(getObj());
console.log(arr);
```

So, I'm wondering if these two lines of code do exactly the same thing or if there is something I'm missing?

The resulting arrays (top array first method with `fill + map` bottom array is only using `map`):

[image]

Comment: I agree, this is absolutely redundant

Comment: Nice, good 2 know

Comment: These are *not* the same; one calls `getObj` once, one calls it for each array entry. There's no reason to do anything this way, though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Array(3).fill(getObj())` will fill your array with references to the same object, `Array(3).fill(null).map(getObj)` will create object per element. See the example below:

```js
const getObj = () => {
  return {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
}

const arr = Array(3).fill(null).map(getObj);
arr[0].b = 4;
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));

const arr1 = Array(3).fill(getObj());
arr1[0].b = 4;
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1));
```

Comment: Ah, I see now. It makes sense now why `.fill + .map` is used now. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to [`Array.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) it is stated in the documentation that:

> When fill gets passed an object, it will copy the reference and fill
> the array with references to that object.

So using a `Array.fill` with objects has somewhat limited application unless you really want to have multiple objects pointing to the **same reference**. In more than few use cases however that would lead to **bugs** if not understood.

---

For the 2nd case where you do  `Array(3).fill(null).map(getObj)` this is one of the ways to create a new array based on a given arbitrary size and at the same time fill it with new objects.

The real need for the `fill(null)` is due to the fact that calling `Array(3)` would only do one thing. Create a new array and set its `length` property to 3. That is it!

```js
let arr = Array(3); // returns new array with its "length" property set to 3

console.log(arr); // [empty × 3]  <-- browser console
```

So that array now has only length and bunch of `empty` elements. You can't do much with it until it actually has values. Therefore the need for `fill` so that you give it any value and then `map` through it to set the values you actually want. Using `Array.map` and calling each iteration your function guarantees you do not have same references. You could have skipped the `fill` step and done something like this:

```js
const getObj = () => ({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3});

// using array destructuring
let arr = [...Array(3)].map(getObj);
arr[0].a = 3;
console.log(arr);

// using Array.from
let arr2 = Array.from(Array(3)).map(getObj);
arr2[0].a = 3;
console.log(arr2);
```

There are somewhat shorter and get you the exact same result of filling the array with specified length with objects and not references to the same object.

The trick here is that both would "fill" the array after it is defined with `undefined` values instead, after which the `map` would fill it with the values we want.

Comment: Do we really need `fill(null)` if we want to fill an array with `getObj` by value? In other words, what's the difference between `Array(3).fill(null).map(getObj);` vs. `Array(3).map(getObj)`? Don't we get the same result?

Answer (score 1):

One thing no other answer has brought up is that the `Array.from` function optionally accepts a mapping function for the array you provide:

```js
const getObj = () => ({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3});

// Array.from also accepts ArrayLikes. 
// As such, constructing an array is unnecessary.
const arr = Array.from({length: 3}, getObj);

arr[0].a = 0;

console.log(arr[0]); // outputs {a: 0, b: 2, c: 3}
console.log(arr[1]); // outputs {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
console.log(arr[2]); // outputs {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```